# PHP: Dumb URL down to its directory

Tags: php, parsing, url

I see questions asking how to get the current directory and such, but I want to take an absolute URL and strip the file out of it (IF there is a file -- I must be able to accept URLs without them too). So, for example.

```
Original: http://www.example.com/index.html
New: http://www.example.com/

Original: http://www.example.com/dir/welcome/index.html
New: http://www.example.com/dir/welcome/
```

I can't figure out how to do this, though it sounds really easy. Any guides, functions, or solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dirname()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) for that, and add a special case for when there is no file

```
<?php
function getUrlDirectory($url) {
  return substr($url, -1) == '/' ? $url : dirname($url).'/';
}

$urls = array(
  'http://www.example.com/index.html',
  'http://www.example.com/dir/welcome/index.html',
  'http://www.example.com/no/file/',
);

foreach ($urls as $url) {
  echo getUrlDirectory($url)."\n";
}
```

When run it gives:

```
$ php test.php 
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/dir/welcome/
http://www.example.com/no/file/
```

Comment: I am aware of parse_url, but its 'path' receives the file name included with the directories, right?

Comment: @BetaBlaze: sorry, I misunderstood the second case, I edited my answer